# Unable to initialize the Alt unity Driver using Appium

Tags: unity-game-engine, appium-android, appium-ios, browserstack, appium-java

Failed to connect to AltUnity Tester on host: 127.0.0.1 port: 13000.

private void connectunity() {

```
  AltUnityPortForwarding.forwardAndroid();    
  try {
  altdriver = new AltUnityDriver();
  }catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
      e.printStackTrace();
  
}
```

}

I'm trying to connect to AltUnity server using appium, Im connect to port 13000 and "the AltUnity pop up waiting for connection on port 13000" disappearing after connection but still unable to initiate the driver getting the error.

note: I've referred the docs related to altunity but and tried different ways to initialize the alt unity driver but none of them are working